# How to position end of div to the left of the container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a floating bubble with a message positioned to the left of the bubble, I have done so using absolute positioning and setting a fixed value for `left` property. However when the message text changes, the div width gets reduced/expanded and it moves away from the bubble.

How should I position it so that the floating message stays to the left of the bubble irrespective of the text?

Here's the code:

```js
var floatingMessage = document.querySelector("#floating-message");
var toggleBtn = document.querySelector("#toggleMessage");
var messages = ["Hello There , chat with us!", "Hello There ", "Welcome!", "blah blah", "looooooooooooooooooooonoooooooooooooog text"];
var currentIndex = 0;
toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % messages.length;
    floatingMessage.textContent = messages[currentIndex];
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: calibri;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#floating-bubble {
    background-color: teal;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2147483645;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thin-communication-messaging/57/thin-036_bubble_comment_chat_message-512.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#floating-message {
  background: #3a96dd;
    padding: 5px;
    left: -180px;
    transition: none;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-name: slidein,wiggle;
    animation-iteration-count: 1,4;
    animation-direction: normal,alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in,ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleMessage">
Toggle Message
</button>
<div id="floating-bubble">
<div id="floating-message">Hello There , chat with us!</div>
</div>
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyberpirate92/jxvkosmp/7/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple, use this:

For `#floating-message` use `right: 60px` (*`60px`, because `50px` are being used by `#floating-bubble`*) and remove the `left` style, so that the message will stick to the end of screen, but now it sometimes gets in two lines, so to fix that use `white-space: nowrap`.

Also, I think that using `2147483645` for `z-index` in `#floating-bubble` is redundant, I've changed that to `2`, just in case some other element has `1`.

```js
var floatingMessage = document.querySelector("#floating-message");
var toggleBtn = document.querySelector("#toggleMessage");
var messages = ["Hello There , chat with us!", "Hello There ", "Welcome!", "blah blah", "looooooooooooooooooooonoooooooooooooog text"];
var currentIndex = 0;
toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % messages.length;
    floatingMessage.textContent = messages[currentIndex];
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: calibri;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#floating-bubble {
    background-color: teal;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thin-communication-messaging/57/thin-036_bubble_comment_chat_message-512.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#floating-message {
  background: #3a96dd;
    padding: 5px;
    right: 60px;    /* Added right over here, so that message stick to the end of screen */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Added this over here, so that it forces the message to be in single line */
    transition: none;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-name: slidein,wiggle;
    animation-iteration-count: 1,4;
    animation-direction: normal,alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in,ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleMessage">
Toggle Message
</button>
<div id="floating-bubble">
<div id="floating-message">Hello There , chat with us!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `position: absolute;` for `#floating-message` you can use `position: fixed;` and give it desired `right` and `bottom` like you did in `#floating-bubble`

Here is an example:

```js
var floatingMessage = document.querySelector("#floating-message");
var toggleBtn = document.querySelector("#toggleMessage");
var messages = ["Hello There , chat with us!", "Hello There ", "Welcome!", "blah blah", "looooooooooooooooooooonoooooooooooooog text"];
var currentIndex = 0;
toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % messages.length;
    floatingMessage.textContent = messages[currentIndex];
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: calibri;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#floating-bubble {
    background-color: teal;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2147483645;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thin-communication-messaging/57/thin-036_bubble_comment_chat_message-512.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#floating-message {
    background: #3a96dd;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: none;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-name: slidein,wiggle;
    animation-iteration-count: 1,4;
    animation-direction: normal,alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in,ease-in-out;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleMessage">
Toggle Message
</button>
<div id="floating-bubble">
<div id="floating-message">Hello There , chat with us!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#floating-message` isn't centrally aligned with `#floating-bubble`

Comment: @Zlytherin I just showed a way to solve the problem. If he/she understands my solution then positioning `#floating-message` wouldn't be problem I guess !

Answer (score 1):

Just change `left: -180px` to `right: 55px` in `#floating-message` class. That will force the div containing the message grow to left side.

```js
var floatingMessage = document.querySelector("#floating-message");
var toggleBtn = document.querySelector("#toggleMessage");
var messages = ["Hello There , chat with us!", "Hello There ", "Welcome!", "blah blah", "looooooooooooooooooooonoooooooooooooog text"];
var currentIndex = 0;
toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % messages.length;
    floatingMessage.textContent = messages[currentIndex];
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: calibri;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#floating-bubble {
    background-color: teal;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2147483645;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thin-communication-messaging/57/thin-036_bubble_comment_chat_message-512.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#floating-message {
  background: #3a96dd;
    padding: 5px;
    right: 55px;
    transition: none;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-name: slidein,wiggle;
    animation-iteration-count: 1,4;
    animation-direction: normal,alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in,ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleMessage">
Toggle Message
</button>
<div id="floating-bubble">
<div id="floating-message">Hello There , chat with us!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you to wrap both of the elements in a single container and make that container fixed, then you can align the elements inside the container much easier and it has more predictable behavior.

Here is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/vrnyt7ou/

```
<button id="toggleMessage">
    Toggle Message
</button>
<div class="float-container">
  <div id="floating-message">Hello There , chat with us!</div>
  <div id="floating-bubble"></div>
</div>

.float-container {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#floating-bubble {
    background-color: teal;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2147483645;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thin-communication-messaging/57/thin-036_bubble_comment_chat_message-512.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#floating-message {
  margin-right: 15px;
  background: #3a96dd;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: none;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-name: slidein,wiggle;
    animation-iteration-count: 1,4;
    animation-direction: normal,alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in,ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```